# Windbg .logopen file location

Tags: windbg

When using `.logopen logfile.txt` command, where is logfile.txt created? I managed to work around it by specifying absolute path, but am wondering when giving relative path where is file created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version 6.3.9600, WinDbg help says in `.hh .logfile`:

> If you do not specify a path, the debugger uses the current directory.

For me, I installed WinDbg in the program files directory.

```
5:kd> .dbgdbg
0:025> |
.  0    id: 29fc        attach  name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\windbg.exe
```

Using Process Monitor, I can see that WinDbg tries to create the logfile there (and fails for permission reasons).

When I cange the working directory in the WinDbg LNK file I use for starting it, it opens the log file in that directory.

[image: Change workding directory in WIndows]

I cannot confirm @blabbs answer, since my home directory is

```
5: kd> !homedir
Home directory is C:\ProgramData\dbg
```

in both cases (running from `%ProgramFiles%` and running from `D:\temp`). If I change `!homedir`, the location of `.logfile` is not affected.

Comment: Using Process Monitor I found where the file was created. It wasn't in homedir `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64` (in my case), but instead in one level above (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers`).

Answer (score 1):

edit

the log file is created in current directory from where windbg was invoked not in homedir i always run windbg from start run (winkey +r -> windbg) and apparently it starts windbg from the installation folder and inherits the directory as well it seems

starting windbg from different folders make the logfile be created in respective current directories

```
>md windbglogtestone
>cd windbglogtestone
\windbglogtestone>cdb -c ".logopen mylog.txt;q" cdb
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.16299.15 X86

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.logopen mylog.txt;q'
Opened log file 'mylog.txt'
quit:

\windbglogtestone>cd ..

>md windbglogtestwo
>cd windbglogtestwo
\windbglogtestwo>cdb -c ".logopen mylog.txt;q" cdb
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.16299.15 X86

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.logopen mylog.txt;q'
Opened log file 'mylog.txt'
quit:

\windbglogtestwo>cd ..

>dir /s /b *my*.txt
\windbglogtestone\mylog.txt
\windbglogtestwo\mylog.txt
```

<s>it is created in the home directory where home represents the folder where windbg is installed (normally c:\progra~\w..kits..\debug.....\x..)</s>

see below for a windbg installation in a different path

```
0:000> .logopen mylogfile.txt
Opened log file 'mylogfile.txt'
0:000> !homedir
Home directory is E:\windjs\windbg_16299\x86
0:000> .shell - dir *my*


 Directory of E:\windjs\windbg_16299\x86

02/14/2018  09:07 AM                 0 mylogfile.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  102,247,899,136 bytes free
.shell: Process exited
Press ENTER to continue
```

in response to lieven's comment why the hyphen in .shell command

it represents a null input file
one can pass `input files` to `.shell` for processing instead of `windbg commands`
using  **-i** instead of **-c**
pass a single hyphen to tell there is no input file
only the shell command indicated needs to be done

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers i edited my answer to include why a single hyphen